# Снег - твердое с или мягкая?

Tags: орфоэпия

Сегодня узнал, что снег с мягкой "с" — старомосковское произношение.

Может, у кого-нибудь есть орфоэпические словари? На Грамоте  в словаре Зарвы этого слова нет.

Comment: Интересный обзор старомосковского произношения дан здесь: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yY7zXn2FU3g Был найден в процессе дискуссии, есть ли в Петербурге "дожжи": https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/20882/pronunciation-of-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%8c (см. комменты к вопросу)

Comment: Да, я видел этот вопрос.

Comment: @Alex_ander по поводу єтого ролика. Я не досмотрел пока до конца, но, судя по всему, ведущий хорошо объясняет, но плохо стилизует. Первое, что обращает на себя внимание - отсутствие перехода С' в С в возвратных суффиксах в его речевом потоке. Там совершенно четко должно быть бою[c], стараю[c] и проч. О чем он говорит, но сам не соблюдает. И и еще кое-что по мелочи.

Comment: @Серж А как вы думаете, произношение СН зависит от предшествующей гласной? Например, в слове "песня", "к весне" мы явно смягчаем С. А если взять, например, такое сочетание: это не снег, а дождь. Будем мы здесь смягчать С?

Comment: Предшествующая гласная  может влиять на н, на весь звук, думаю.

Answer (score 3):

Да, вопрос, конечно, интересный и многих волнует, **даже маленьких школьников**. Как известно, им  в наше время без репетитора трудно учиться.

Из Интернета: Пришла от репетитора. Та сказала, что С должно быть **мягким**, потому что СН — это сочетание. Мы пока такого не прошли. Проверяю,  и на многих сайтах написано, что  С — твердый, только в одном показано,  что мягкий. Как вы думаете?
Источник: https://www.stranamam.ru/post/8973520/

Не буду здесь говорить про сочетание СН (это отдельная тема), а про словари такая информация. **У Резниченко (2010)** про мягкий звук С в слове *снег* не сказано ни слова, разбираются только предложные формы. **У Аванесова (1987)** указано, что С — мягкий, там про твердый звук тоже ни слова.

Следовательно, за этот небольшой период **нормы изменились**. Произношение мягкого С в слове *снег* еще не кажется архаичным, но оно явно уступает место твердому С.

Так что неправ репетитор, при фонетическом разборе следует указывать, что С — твердый.

Comment: *У Аванесова (1987) указано, что С — мягкий,* - ой... Правда? Я (как назло) только что убрал свой бумажный в дальний ящик...

Comment: Чистая правда,  и в слове "снегирь" тоже

Comment: Добавлю, что и в редакции **2003**-го года у [Резниченко](http://slovana.ru/slovari/reznichenko/orfoepicheskij-slovar-reznichenko_0956.htm) ни слова о мягком С.

Comment: Да, читал этот комментарий из Интернета.

Comment: Комментарий показался мне примечательным. Во-первых, такая проблема существует и люди пытаются в ней разобраться. Во-вторых, это картинка из жизни нашего общества. Я исправила орфографию в сообщении, но в оригинале много ошибок. Люди, которые сами не очень сильны в  правописании, очень хотят, чтобы дети стали грамотными. И учатся вместе с ними.

Comment: Действительно, проблема существует.

Comment: Проблема в том, что ситуация быстро изменилась и не все об этом информированы. В то же время очевидно, что нужно пользоваться новыми словарями, где звук С считается твердым.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно, разумеется, с твердым С. Его с мягким и произнести-то трудно.

Что же касается старомосковской нормы, то там действительно существовала гораздо более сильная регрессивная ассимиляция согласных по мягкости-твердости. 
Об этом даже в вики написано весьма подробно.

> широко распространено ассимилятивное смягчение согласных: мягкое
>   произношение первого согласного C₁ перед вторым мягким C₂ʲ (в
>   сочетаниях согласных звуков C₁C₂ʲ) имеет место не только, если оба
>   звука переднеязычные (например, [с’т’]епь, [з’д’]есь, и[з’н’]еможение,
>   пе[н’с’]ия, о зо[н’т’]е, но и в остальных случаях: [д’в’]ерь,
>   е[с’л’]и, [з’]верь, ко[р’]ни, [с’]вет, [с’]мирный и т. п.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Но ситуация такова, что эта старомосковская норма ушла безвозвратно. Сейчас сохранились разве что отдельные рудиментарные случаи подобного употребления. 
Ко всему прочему, сам пример со словом "снег" не слишком удачен. Дело в том, что рассматриваемая ассимиляция не была императивной, некоторые слова сопротивлялись подобному. **Снег** - из их числа. Если смягчение первого звука и было, то неполное, причина тому - сочетание "с+сонорная" - с резким повышение шумности, что препятствует ассимиляции.    Более убедительные примеры - в цитате из вики.

Comment: @Серж: странно, я всю жизнь мягко произношу "снег". И "борщ" тоже. И "если". Не вижу сложностей с таким произношением.

Comment: Борщ - я тоже мягко произношу. И снег тоже. В комментарии я хотел написать: мне тяжело произносить с твердым с.

Comment: А-а, тогда конечно! Согласен) Я вначале и подумал, что вы удивляетесь, что это старомосковское, а не вообще единственно правильное, а потом ваш комментарий меня сбил.

Comment: *я всю жизнь мягко произношу "снег"* - ой ли? Ну это только слушать надо... Подозреваю, что там у вас полумягкое. Достать бы записи спектаклей Малого времен довоенных... Вот там бы послушать. Все что есть современного не дает достаточной информации, но сомнительно, что там полноценное смягчение.. Ну в общем этот отдельный разговор...  *И "борщ" тоже. И "если".* - тут-то проблем нет. Мой речевой аппарат вполне приспособлен к такому, хотя и выглядит совершенно неправильным.

Comment: Начало у меня, как у manyaha, а конец обычно как у Durakalzar здесь: https://forvo.com/word/%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3/#ru.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Ясно. Ну собственно, я и не слышу своими с детства чуточку туговатыми ушами полноценного смягчения ни у кого из представленного списка. А вот окончание - это да... Вас надо в кино снимать вместе с этим Durakalzar в исторических фильмах, коли вы вслед за Пушкиным рифмуете "[просвещенья] дух" и " "[парадоксов] друг". Только это не "старомосковская" норма, это орфоэпия всего языка до первой половины XVIII века...  Но ладно, переход велярного Г ([ɣ]) во взрывной - это отдельная тема...

Comment: Спасибо за комплимент про кино (я воспринял так). :)) *...это орфоэпия всего языка до первой половины XVIII века* — а не XIX имели в виду? Или в XIX это уже только частично осталось?

Comment: @behemothus А почему у Аванесова обозначено смягчение, если его произнести трудно?

Comment: @Sharon Извините, не ответил сразу. Отвлекся - и забыл. Только сейчас вспомнил, случайно наткнувшись на этот вопрос. Но, собственно, ответить-то мне и нечего. Не знаю. Видимо, мы с Аванесовым по-разному понимаем это смягчение. И естественно, что я, не имея аргументов, споритить с ним не буду.

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень приятно, что вы так внимательны.

Comment: Мне всё-таки хочется разобраться: вы говорите, что "это орфоэпия всего языка до первой половины XVIII века". А во времена Пушкина-то насколько это ещё осталось, когда он так рифмовал? Он уже выделялся из других, говоря так? Как думаете, то время в этом аспекте ближе к нынешнему или к указанному выше периоду?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Пушкин так рифмовал в силку поэтической традиции, в этом он не сильно отличался от своих современников-поэтов.  В быту, заговори он так, он показался бы человеком южнорусского или малороссийского происхождения (таких было много в столицах). Хотя были и носители старой нормы. Строго говоря, современное украинское Г несколько отличается от исторического славянского Г, но на русский слух они похожи до смешения. На вопрос, что там к чему ближе, ответить не могу. Ибо есть два звука, исторический плавный Г и современный взрывной (с украинским - три, но его выносим за скобки).

Comment: Какого-то среднего, промежуточного между ними не наблюдалось. Произношение менялось постепенно - по ареалам, по численности говолрящих, , но не плавно, поэтому ваш заключительный вопрос представляется мне некорректным. Все, что могу сказать, Во времена Пушкина переход к взрывному Г в целом закончился. Возможно, специалисты по исторической фонетики могут добавить много всего интересного, но я, простите, в этом вопросе не более, чем  обычный дилетант.

Comment: Спасибо большое, и так много полезного нашёл! ;)